# Is there another option for jquery opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity, uislider

I have a series of sliders that control the items / links on my site. http://wp11004271.server-he.de/alloytoy4.0/. At the moment there is only two options for these links, available (dark background) and unavailable (light background). I would like to add some in-between variables for links that are available in another capacity.

```
        var filter = {};
        var unmarkItem = function (alloy) {
            var domalloy = $('#alloy_' + alloy);
            domalloy.css('opacity', 1);
            //    alloys[alloy].marked = false;
        };
        var markItem = function (alloy) {
            var domalloy = $('#alloy_' + alloy);
            domalloy.css('opacity', 0.2);
            //    alloys[alloy].marked = true;
        };
```

Iam only familiar with true or false but want to add other options.
Any thoughts on what to add?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You are clearly showing that setting the opacity to anything other than 0 or 1 (true/false) is possible with your `.2` value...

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using `marked` as a Boolean, which means, that it can only be two values assigned to: `true` or `false`.

If you want more options, I would recommend to use `marked` as an Integer, means a number without any decimal places (guess thats the right word for it, if not, correct me) so without a comma.

Create variables called for example `MODE_DISABLED`, `MODE_INACTIVE`, `MODE_ACTIVE`, etc. and assign number values to them, like `var MODE_DISABLED = 1;` or something like that.

Then you can set the modes like

```
alloys[alloy].marked = MODE_INACTIVE;
```

and dont have to keep in mind whats the value for which mode.

Your function `markItem` should get a second parameter for the value.

Comment: Thanks Tom I will give this a try.